# Docker-compose for nginx, php, mysql, golang

Tags: php, docker, go, docker-compose, cron

The server is now working with this configuration.

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
        depends_on:
            - php
    php:
        build: ./docker/images/php
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
    mysql:
        image: mysql       
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./docker/import:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

Dockerfile for php image

```
# Main image
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Update and install modules for php and other
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \      
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && apt-get install -y wget zip unzip git \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd pdo mysqli pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

# Workdir for php
WORKDIR /var/www

# Run container
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

I want to add `golang` container to this config so that I can run the execution `golang` files from `cron`.

Questions are:

- What is the best way to do this?
- How to add it specifically to `docker-compose` / `Dockerfile` and run from `cron`?

Comment: You can add next service in `docker-compose.yml` and setup cron on host machine. You can write daemon in `go` like `while (true) { if (isTimeToRun()) { run(); } sleep(1); }`.
Here you have nice example where is web app and daemon https://github.com/phabricator-docker/phabricator/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### == Option 1: add `docker-compose` to `crontab` ==

```
* * * * * cd <project dir>/docker-compose && command docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run --rm -T -w /go/bin <go_app_container> <go_app_name>
```

### == Option 2: use `cron-docker` ==

Here is a [Docker images to run cron inside the Docker container](https://github.com/renskiy/cron-docker-image)

- `Debian`-based: [Dockerfile](https://github.com/renskiy/cron-docker-image/blob/master/debian/Dockerfile), [start-cron](https://github.com/renskiy/cron-docker-image/blob/master/debian/start-cron)
- `Alpine`-based: [Dockerfile](https://github.com/renskiy/cron-docker-image/blob/master/alpine/Dockerfile), [start-cron](https://github.com/renskiy/cron-docker-image/blob/master/alpine/start-cron)

#### Adding cron jobs with  `cron-docker`

Suppose you have folder `cron.d` with your cron scripts. The only thing you have to do is copying this folder into the Docker image:

```
# Dockerfile

FROM renskiy/cron:debian

COPY cron.d /etc/cron.d
```

Then build and create container:

```
docker build --tag my_cron .
docker run --detach --name cron my_cron
```

#### View logs

To view logs use Docker [logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) command:

```
docker logs --follow cron
```

*All you cron scripts should write logs to `/var/log/cron.log`. Otherwise you won't be able to view any log using this way.*

#### Passing cron jobs by arguments

Additionally you can pass any cron job by argument(s) using custom `start-cron` command at the moment of container creation (providing optional user with `-u`/`--user` option):

```
docker run --detach --name cron renskiy/cron:debian start-cron --user www-data \
    "0 1 \\* \\* \\* echo '01:00 AM' &gt;&gt; /var/log/cron.log 2&gt;&1" \
    "0 0 1 1 \\* echo 'Happy New Year!!' &gt;&gt; /var/log/cron.log 2&gt;&1"
```

#### Environment variables

Almost any environ variable you passed to the Docker will be visible to your cron scripts. With the exception of `$SHELL`, `$PATH`, `$PWD`, `$USER`, etc.

```
docker run --tty --rm --interactive --env MY_VAR=foo renskiy/cron:debian start-cron \
    "\\* \\* \\* \\* \\* env &gt;&gt; /var/log/cron.log 2&gt;&1"
```

### == Option 3: use `cron-docker` with `docker-compose` ==

For your case:

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
        depends_on:
            - php
    php:
        build: ./docker/images/php
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www
    mysql:
        image: mysql       
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./docker/import:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        environment:
            MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    cron_go_app:
      image: renskiy/cron:alpine
      volumes:
        - crontabs:/etc/crontabs
        - my_go_app:/app/my_go_app
      run: start-cron
```